# Error al ingresar datos de una consulta SQL a un DataGridView vb.net y sql

Tags: sql, vb.net, combobox, datagridview

les platico mi problema:

Estoy trabajando en un sistema el cual tiene **dos combobox** y **un datagridview**. El primer combobox muestra el horario de una escuela y el segundo combobox muestra a los alumnos inscritos en ese horario antes mencionado, por lo que primero se tiene que seleccionar un horario en el combobox1 para que carguen los nombres de los alumnos en el combobox2. Ademas, cuando selecciono un horario, el datagridview se llena con los datos de los alumnos que están en el horario seleccionado.

Entonces, al seleccionar un horario(combobox1), se meten los valores en el combobox2 y ademas, me muestra la información de todos los alumnos inscritos en ese horario en el datagridview. Todo esto lo hago con **métodos** y el evento **SelectionChangeCommited** del combobox, a continuación les dejo el código:

```
  Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectionChangeCommitted(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectionChangeCommitted
    DataGridView1.DataSource = Nothing
    insertarAlumnos()    'Inserta alumnos de X horario en combobox2'
    horario = ComboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString()

    getTodosLosAlumnos(horario)
    DataGridView1.Refresh()
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox2_SelectionChangeCommitted(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox2.SelectionChangeCommitted
    DataGridView1.DataSource = Nothing
    idAlumno = ComboBox2.SelectedValue.ToString()
    getAlumno(idAlumno)
    DataGridView1.Refresh()
End Sub


Public Sub insertarAlumnos()
    Dim horario As String
    horario = ComboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString()
    Dim consulta = " SELECT id, (CONVERT(varchar, nombre) + ' ' +  apellido_paterno + ' ' + apellido_materno) AS DatosCombinados FROM alumnos where horario='" & horario & "'"

    Using cn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=LAPTOP-2G254V6A\EQUIPO;Initial Catalog=registraTKD;Integrated Security=True")
        cn.Open()
        Dim da As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(consulta, cn)
        Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable("alumnos")
        da.Fill(dt)

        ComboBox2.DataSource = dt
        ComboBox2.DisplayMember = "alumnos"
        ComboBox2.ValueMember = "DatosCombinados"
        idAlumno = dt.Rows.Item(0).Item(0).ToString()
        cn.Close()
    End Using

End Sub

Sub getAlumno(idAlumno As String)
    Using cn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=LAPTOP-2G254V6A\EQUIPO;Initial Catalog=registraTKD;Integrated Security=True")
        Dim consulta = "Select  (CONVERT(varchar, nombre) + ' ' +  apellido_paterno + ' ' + apellido_materno) AS Nombre_del_alumno,
         mes as Mes , monto as Costo_de_mensualidad, status_mensualidad as Estado
        from alumnos 
        inner join mensualidades on alumnos.id = mensualidades.id
        where alumnos.id=" & idAlumno

        cn.Open()

        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(consulta, cn)
        Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable("Alumno")
        da.Fill(dt)

        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
        cn.Close()
    End Using



End Sub

Sub getTodosLosAlumnos(horario As String)
    Using cn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=LAPTOP-2G254V6A\EQUIPO;Initial Catalog=registraTKD;Integrated Security=True")

        Dim consulta = "Select  (CONVERT(varchar, nombre) + ' ' +  apellido_paterno + ' ' + apellido_materno) AS Nombre_del_alumno,
         mes as Mes , monto as Costo_de_mensualidad, status_mensualidad as Estado
        from alumnos 
        inner join mensualidades on alumnos.id = mensualidades.id
        where alumnos.horario='" & horario & "'"

        cn.Open()

        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(consulta, cn)
        Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable("Control de pagos")
        da.Fill(dt)

        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
        cn.Close()

    End Using
End Sub
```

Mi problema está al usar el evento **SelectionChangeCommited** del combobox2 (nombre de alumnos inscritos en el horario seleccionado). Si se fijan, el evento SelectionChangeCommited del combobox1 y combobox2 tienen dentro el mismo codigo, casi. La unica diferencia está en la consulta SQL, en la parte de la condicion Where. 
El código del SelectionChangeCommited en el primer combobox corre perfectamente. Me muestra lo que yo quiero, pero en el segundo evento no es asi. Me lanza un error diciendo:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near 'Jimenez'.'

Me tira el error en esta parte:

```
 Sub getAlumno(idAlumno As String)
    Using cn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=LAPTOP-2G254V6A\EQUIPO;Initial Catalog=registraTKD;Integrated Security=True")
        Dim consulta = "Select  (CONVERT(varchar, nombre) + ' ' +  apellido_paterno + ' ' + apellido_materno) AS Nombre_del_alumno,
         mes as Mes , monto as Costo_de_mensualidad, status_mensualidad as Estado
        from alumnos 
        inner join mensualidades on alumnos.id = mensualidades.id
        where alumnos.id=" & idAlumno

        cn.Open()

        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(consulta, cn)
        Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable("Alumno")
        da.Fill(dt)   'Aquí me lanza el error'

        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
        cn.Close()
    End Using

End Sub
```

¿Alguna idea de que pueda ser?

Comment: Te da error en el fill porqué es cuando llena el resultado de la consulta. Podrías ejecutar la consulta en SQL Server y poner el resultado en la pregunta? (en forma de imagen)

Comment: Amigo, debugea hasta que declaras tu datatable y saca un pantallazo de eso, tienes que ver como llegan tus datos aunque por el error que te dio parece ser un error de consulta, igual te pediría un pantallazo de como termina hecha tu consulta, lo pones en inspeccion o watch para ver y te ayudo.